# My jest unit test case is failing for Material UI multi select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I am trying to write a unit test case for material UI multi select.

Parent component code is -

```
import {myData} from '../constant';
export const Parent = () => {    
 const onChangeStatus= (selectedValues: Array<string>) => {
        setTest({
                   ...test,
                   values: selectedValues
                });
    }      
  return (
            <Child
                onChange={onChangeStatus}
                myData={test}
            />
    );      
}
```

Child Component code is -

```
import React from 'react'
export interface ChildProps {
    onChangeStatus: (values: Array<string>) => void;
    myData?: Array<Test<string, string>> | null;
}

export const Child = ({onChangeStatus , myData}: ChildProps) => {  
  return (
        <div>
            <MultiSelect
                multiple
                native
                value={myData.val}
                onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>): void => {
                        const { selectedOptions } = event.target;
                        let values: string[] = Array.from(selectedOptions).map(selectedOption => selectedOption.value);
                        onChangeStatus(values);
                         }}>
                            {myData &&
                                myData.multiSelectData &&
                                myData.multiSelectData.map(
                                    (item: Test<string, string>) => (
                                        <option key={item.key} value={item.value}>
                                            {item.key.replace('_',' ')}
                                        </option>
                                    )
                                )}
                        </MultiSelect>
        </div>
    );
    
}
```

This is what I have written the test cases  -

```
it('should call onChange handler when test multi select is selected', () => {
        const event = {target: { value: 'All', key: 'All' }};
        wrapper
            .find(MultiSelect)
            .first()
            .props()
            .onChange('test', event);
        expect(mockOnChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

This test case is failing. Getting error like - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedOptions' of undefined`. Also code is not covered for this function.
Can anyone help me in that to pass the test case and get 100% code coverage for multi select.

Answer (score 1):

You should do `onChange(event)`, without the `test` string on it because your function receives only one prop, not two.

There's another problem with the `event` mocked in the test. You need to defined the `selectedOptions` property because you are using it in the component. Something like this:

`const event = {target: { selectedOptions: [{ value: 'All', key: 'All' }] } };`

Also, regarding your test, you can improve it by checking with what arguments your mocked function was called. It will validate that you are passing the correct values to it. Something like this:

```
expect(mockOnChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['All']);
```

Comment: I did the same. Now I am getting `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` error. I think error is at `Array.from(selectedOptions).map(selectedOption => selectedOption.value);` line.

Comment: Oh ye, sorry, I missed that. It's because you are accessing `selectedOptions` from the target and you don't defined it on the `event` in the test. I will change my reply

Comment: Now it is saying , `expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected);`
   `Expected: ["All"]`
   `Number of calls: 0`
Error at this line  - `expect(mockOnChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['All']);`

Comment: Can you add the code of your test? I don't know how you are declaring the mock function and the `wrapper`